# JavaScriptでURLに応じて処理を実行する時にオススメな方法はありますか

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, vue.js

私はrailsとvue.jsを組み合わせて使っています。railsでは最終的にjsが1つになる仕組みがあるため一つのjsで複数のURLに対応したいと思っています。

そこで次のようなコードを作成しました。

```
if matchs = location.pathname.match("/categories/(.*)")
  window.superagent.get("/api/v1/categories/" + matchs[1] + ".json")
.end (err, res) ->
  vue_category.category = res.body
```

本当は次のようにしたいと考えています。

```
Router.set("/categories/:id") = (id) ->
  vue_category.category = res.body
Router.run()
```

このような事ができるライブラリやスタンダートなやり方は何かあるのでしょうか。
または、URLで振り分けしたいのはわかるがJavaScript的にそれはないみたいな話もあると思っています。

vue-routerも検討してみたのですが、vue-routerは単一ページ内で画面を切り替えるための機能で、実際のURLに応じて処理する機能では無さそうと認識していて今回の用途には合わないのかなと思っています。（Twitter経由で助言を頂き、vue-routerでも出来る可能性があると指摘されていて調査中です）

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

@mizchi/routerを使用すると目的を達成できそうです。
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mizchi/router

Twitter経由で教えていただきました。
https://twitter.com/_ringogirl/status/702009261220450304